# how to match items in two columns based on specific criteria in excel?

Tags: excel

I have Column A and Column B as:

```
ColA         ColB
12345-678    12345678_A
23456-789    23456789_B
```

And so on.

I would like to know how to match elements by setting a criteria where I can match 12345-678 with 12345678?

Comment: What do you want the final outcome to be? Sort? Filter? Count? You showed example input data but can you provide us sample *output* data?

Comment: After matching the two, Col C must contain '12345678'. I'm new to excel manipulations.

Comment: @pnuts It's just an example. The mechanism applies to all elements in the Columns A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""),B2)),"",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))
```